# Word count program with two input files and single output file

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, word-count

I am new to Hadoop. I have done word count program with single input file and single output file. Now I want to take 2 files as input and write that output to a single file. I tried like this:

```
FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]), new Path(args[1]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[2]));
```

This is the command in terminal:

```
hadoop jar test.jar Driver /user/in.txt /user/sample.txt /user/out
```

When I run this, its taking sample.txt as output directory and says that :

```
Output directory hdfs://localhost:9000/user/sample.txt already exists
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Just wanted to know how did you made the Jar..Is it a normal jar or runnable jar...If runnable jar then you dont have to mention the  driver class name ....

Comment: It was a runnable jar, so I removed Driver and it worked. Thanks Aman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be because it is taking Driver as your first argument. why don't you try like this.

```
hadoop jar test.jar /user/in.txt /user/sample.txt /user/out
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have all the input files in one folder as you have mentioned (`/user`), the replace

```
hadoop jar test.jar Driver /user/in.txt /user/sample.txt /user/out
```

with this

```
hadoop jar test.jar Driver /user /user/out
```

This takes all the file inside `/user` directory as input and outputs in `user/out` folder in HDFS.